# Simple form error: Mysql::Error: Column 'cached_slug'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, friendly-url

I get this error when I submit my kategori form:

ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid in KategorisController#create

Mysql::Error: Column 'cached_slug' cannot be null: INSERT INTO `kategoris`

Here is my form:

```
<%= simple_form_for(@kategori) do |f| %>

    <%= f.input :name %>
    <%= f.button :submit %>
<% end %>
```

Here is my controller:

```
 # GET /kategoris/new.xml
  def new
    @kategori = Kategori.new

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # new.html.erb
      format.xml  { render :xml => @kategori }
    end
  end

  # GET /kategoris/1/edit
  def edit
    @kategori = Kategori.find(params[:id])
  end

  # POST /kategoris

  # POST /kategoris.xml
  def create
    @kategori = Kategori.new(params[:kategori])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @kategori.save
        format.html { redirect_to(@kategori, :notice => 'Kategori was successfully created.') }
        format.xml  { render :xml => @kategori, :status => :created, :location => @kategori }
      else
        format.html { render :action => "new" }
        format.xml  { render :xml => @kategori.errors, :status => :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

And should I rename ID to friendly_id?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you need to populate the `cached_slug` field in your model before it can be saved. Usually you can use a pattern like this:

```
class Kategori < ActiveRecord::Base
  before_save :assign_cached_slug, :unless => :cached_slug?

protected
  def assign_cached_slug
    self.cached_slug = self.title.gsub(/\s+/, '_').gsub(/[^\w\-]/, '')
  end
end
```

You can use whatever *slugification* system you need. The one given here is just an example.

Answer (score 0):

It seems the column cached_slug in the database is not nullable in the database level itself. So, the error is happening. You can get rid of this by using Tadman's code.